# How to expose IFrame's DOM using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a prototype representing a particual IFrame. That prototype have a function called GoToUrl(...) that opens the given url within the IFrame.

My question is: How do I create an "InternalDOM" property and make this property refer to the "window" object (the root DOM object) of the IFrame inside? In such way that: If my IFrame exposes a page which has an object X in it's "window" object I could do:

```
MyFrameObject.GoToUrl(pageXurl);
MyFrameObject.InternalDOM.X
```

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I would accept answers not necessarily related to jQuery but I would prefer a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To get the `window` object for a frame you can use the `window.frames` array:

```
var iframewindow= frames['iframe_name'];
```

This requires that you give the `<iframe>` an old-school `name` attribute instead-of-or-as-well-as the `id`. Alternatively if you know the order of iframes on the page you can index them numerically:

```
var iframewindow= frames[0];
```

It's generally more flexible to get the iframe window from the iframe element in the DOM, but this requires some compatibility code to cope with IE:

```
var iframe= document.getElementById('iframe_id');
var iframewindow= iframe.contentWindow? iframe.contentWindow : iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;
```

jQuery defines the [contents()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents) method to grab the `document` node, but it doesn't give you a cross-browser way to go from the `document` to the `window`, so you're still stuck with:

```
var iframe= $('#iframe_id')[0];
var iframewindow= iframe.contentWindow? iframe.contentWindow : iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;
```

which isn't really a big win.

(Note: be very careful using jQuery for cross-frame-scripting. Each frame needs its own copy of jQuery and methods from one frame's copy won't necessarily work on nodes from the other. Cross-frame-scripting is a topic fraught with traps.)

Comment: http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/iframe_talks_to_parent/ - a good example and explanation about cross-iframe-scripting

Comment: I prefer `$('#iframe-id').get(0).contentWindow`

Answer (score 39):

## To sum it up

#### Access iframe content from parent page

```
var iframe = $('iframe').contents(); // iframe.find('..') ...
```

#### Access parent page content from iframe

```
var parent = $(window.parent.document); // parent.find('..') ...
```

This applies only when the parent and the iframe pages are on same domain.

## EDIT: On load child iframes example:

### parent html

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="iframe1.html"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2" src="iframe2.html"></iframe>
```

### parent js

```
$(function () {
    var iframe1 = null,
        iframe2 = null;

    // IE8/7
    var frameInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
        iframe1 = $('#iframe1').contents();
        iframe2 = $('#iframe2').contents();
        if ($('head', iframe1).length && $('head', iframe2).length) {
            window.clearInterval(frameInterval);
        }
    }, 100);

    // on iframe loaded
    $('#iframe1').on('load', function (e) {
        iframe1 = $('#iframe1').contents();
    });
    $('#iframe2').on('load', function (e) {
        iframe2 = $('#iframe2').contents();
    });
});
```

All major browsers including IE9 work with the `on('load')` lines. Only IE8/7 need the interval block.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE @RoyiNamir 's comment:

```
var frames = window.frames || window.document.frames;
```

for window in a iframe.

```
frames["myIframeId"].window
```

for document in a iframe

```
frames["myIframeId"].window.document
```

for body in a iframe

```
frames["myIframeId"].window.document.body
```

for body in a iframe with jquery

```
var iframeBody = $(frames["myIframeId"].window.document).contents().find("body");
```

IMPORTANT:
you should always check that the document is with the status "complete" for work with this

```
if (frames["myIframeId"].window.document.readyState=="complete")
{
   //ok
}
else
{
   //perform a recursive call until it is complete
}
```

Comment: @andres descalzo I haven't been surveying changes since you wrote this answer, but `window.document.frames` doesn't work anymore, atleast not in Firefox and Chrome. Editing your post.

Comment: @RoyiNamir thanks for the clarification, in IE works fine but is not compatible with other browsers