# Need help in Javascript + IFrame

Tags: javascript

I have 2 function one in iframe and another one out of iframe.

I want to call outer function from inner[iframe] function.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `parent` attribute to go up in levels, and to the holder of the iframe to call its functions.

Comment: function foxbee()
{
 obj = '<?PHP echo($objectName); ?>';
 val = document.getElementById(obj).value;
 if(window.parent.beagod())
 {
  alert("okay");
  parent.beagod();
  
 }
 else
 {
  alert("never");
 }
 //document.parent.beagod(val);
}

Comment: `function respondToComment(comment) { if(comment.contains(code) && !(comment.contains(question) || comment.contains(remark))) { alert('I\'m not sure what you're trying to say here.'); }`

Comment: `parent.functionName()` should do the trick. Are you certain that your JavaScript is being executed properly and that the function you're calling always returns `true`?

Answer (score 0):

[This is a good answered question about cross frame javascript function calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery). Although the title mentions jQuery the answer is pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

Answers relying on the parent object will only work if your iframes are hosted on the same domain.  If going across domains, you'll need [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).  The [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) library may provide the functionality you need in an easier to use (IE6/7 friendly) package, but I've never used it.