# iframe onload in IE7/8 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, onload

I have an iframe loading into a parent page.  The iframe contains a sequence of forms, and I'd like to take action on the parent page every time the iframe content in reloaded (ie, after a form is submitted in the iframe content).  The current code is located on the parent page and works in all the big players except IE (I'm only concerned with IE 7 & 8).

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('theiframe');
function refresh( ) {
  alert('foo');
}
if (iframe.attachEvent) iframe.attachEvent('onload', refresh);
else iframe.onload = refresh;
```

What am I missing that would prevent this from being effective in IE?

Comment: Try referencing the iframe's document: var iframe = document.getElementById('theiframe').document; (not an answer because I'm guessing :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
iframe.onload = refresh
```

with:

```
iframe.attachEvent('load', refresh, false);
```

---

To clear any confusion:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('theiframe');
function refresh( ) {
  alert('foo');
}

if (iframe.attachEvent) iframe.attachEvent('onload', refresh);
else iframe.addEventListener('load', refresh, false)
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `load` and `onload`?

Comment: IE calls the event onload, while must other browsers call it load.

Comment: I did wind up adding an `else if (iframe.addEventListener) ...` clause before the end.  Good call!

Comment: I found IE prefers:  iframe.attachEvent("onload", refresh);

Comment: @SamWatkins, that case is covered in the if statement. If attachEvent is define it uses that.

Comment: If non of this work for you check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11874986/1260020

Comment: This did not work for me for internet explorer 11. 

The alert('foo') fires when the parent page is first loaded; but, does not fire when the form in the iframe is submitted.

Comment: Mark, the question is clearly requesting ie7 and ie8.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it from the `iframe` by calling `parent.refresh()` when you are done with a submit.

Comment: While I ultimately have control over both the parent and iframe, modifying the iframe in any way is prohibitively difficult.

Comment: ok, but sometimes the `onload` event fires, while all the job is not done in the `iframe`. I found adding the "I'm done" command in the iframe more reliable for all browsers.

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter that the iframe contents (resources, DOM, etc) are or aren't finished loading, it just matters that "the user has begun viewing a new page."  Great point though.

Comment: This solution did not work for me in IE 11. The parent page remained unaffected.

Comment: @Mic, my motivation is to provide information to people who are arriving here today from google searches. They will likely be looking for a solution to a current problem; not a problem from 5 years ago.    
    
To reiterate, not a personal attack, merely saving some people some time.

Comment: @Mark, if IE does not accept that anymore, you can use `parent.postMessage` with a listener in the parent's page that will refresh itself