# dynamically change onload for an iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, onload

I have a page containing a couple of `<iframe>` tags. I want to change their onload actions dynamically. I have the following code that works fine in FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera, but IE (8) refuses to comply.

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').onload = function() {
    return function() { file_onLoad(data); }
}();
```

I've been using something similar for setting the `onchange` of an `<input>` element and this works well in all the browsers I've tested, including IE.

```
document.getElementById('myinput').onchange = function() {
    return function() { file_onChange(data); }
}();
```

So I guess it has something to do with the way I'm getting the frame element / object.

I've also tried `frames['myiframe']` but with no success.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works fine on mine...
I tried:

```
function whatever(){
    document.getElementById('myiframe').src="http://www.google.com/"
    document.getElementById('myiframe').onload = function() {
        return function() { alert("Done."); }
    }();
}
```

and it works. (I tried on IE9 with IE8 mode turned on)
If it does not work for you, try this:

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').addEventListener('load', file_onLoad, false);
```

Comment: Read more here: [http://stackoverflow.com/.../iframe-onload-in-ie7-8-with-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455834/iframe-onload-in-ie7-8-with-javascript)