# How do I call a function in jquery after a page has loaded within an iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, document-ready

Basically, I want the iframe to fade out, then load a new url, then fade back in. Right now my code just fades out and (presumably, I can't really see it) loads the new page. I'm using `$('iframe').ready(function(){
 /*code that changes the src of the iframe*/
});`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765356/dynamically-change-onload-for-an-iframe

Comment: I guess I don't understand how to call $(iframe).animate() again from inside the iframe. Both of these seem to use onload functions, but how could I access the opacity of the iframe from the page that is inside the iframe? Maybe I'm just confusing myself.

Comment: You don't have to do anything from inside the iframe. You'll place all your code on the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EcRBv/1/

```
function changeIframe(newSrc){
    $("#iframe1").fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $(this).attr("src",newSrc);
        $(this).load(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn("fast"); 
        });
    });
}

changeIframe("http://www.jsfiddle.net");
```

Comment: It's probably wiser to attach the handler _before_ changing `src` just in case the event somehow manages to fire before your next line was executed.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much! I just needed to change .ready() to .load(), I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score -1):

Either use `.load()` or change the iframe `.attr('src')`, like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('iframe').animate({opacity:0}, 300, function(){
    //load or change source inside this callback     
  })
  $('iframe').animate({opacity:1}, 300};
})
```

Comment: This won't wait for iframe page to load.