# i have to iframe one parent and other child, i want to get child iframe value using jquery, how can i get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

here my code:

```
<div id="biography_name1">
    <iframe id="Array___Frame" src="some_value" height="600" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" >
        <html>
              <head></head>
              <body>
                   <iframe  src="some_value">
                      <div class="my_value"> GET THIS VALUE </div>
                   </iframe> 
              </body>
        </html>
    </iframe> 
</div>
```

here i want to get class my_value values using jquery. how can i do?

Comment: There seems to be no clean-cut way to do it, but [this should answer most of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to upvote and accept an answer if it helps! ;)

```
<iframe id='frameParent'>
    <iframe id='frameChild'>
        <div id="my_value">some text here</div>
    </iframe>
</iframe>
<script>
    var foo = $("#frameParent").contents().find("#frameChild").contents().find(".my_value").text();
    //NOW YOUR VALUE IS STORED IN THE VARIABLE CALLED FOO  
    //change '#' to '.' in last find statement      
</script>
```

Now it should work

Comment: ya dear i was try this one but it will works on only one frame, but i have parent and child frame and i want to get value from child, so how can i get?

Comment: Try again now. I re-edited it taking into account the child frame. Please vote up if it works :)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, very kind Maulik, I hope you get lots of help in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".my_value").text();
```

will do that.