# In jquery mobile, how can you make a list filter controlled by a few buttons instead of typing text?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, filter

Let's say i want to make a conference app that talks about 4 different subjects.
So i have a list with all the events going on during a week. But as a user i want to see only those about biotechnology for ex. But from time to time being able to see all the events would also be nice.

so i just want a page with buttons that can control what i am seeing on the list without working with nested lists. 
So i can still see all the events mixed up on a same day.

thanks for the help

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can have the buttons set specific values to the search filter when they are clicked. You just need to trigger the "keyup" event on the filter, and the list will update. This even works if the filter's input field is hidden, though you still need the listview to have the `data-filter="true"` attribute set.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RfJm/3/) to demonstrate, it uses the same list as the ["Search filter hidden data"](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-search-filtertext.html) example from the jQM docs.

Comment: thanks a lot!! works perfectly! I still have one isue though,  How can you apply those defined search settings too a list loaded in an external list in an inappbrowser of phonegap.. (reason for loading externaly is that it should have it's own styling and these could be a variety of different lists from different websites but all with jquery mobile).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you mean by an externally loaded list (know that I have zero knowledge of phonegap) Is the list you're targeting in a separate web page? Or do you mean you are loading its data through ajax?

Comment: yes, the list i'm loading is either in an iframe or in the "inappbrowser" plugin of phonegap. But controlled via the main app. I'm trying now using the window.postmessage method available in html5. hope it's gonna work!

Comment: doesn't seem to work properly, here's what id did for js script that will appear in the iframe (the idea is to still have control inside the iframe too):

Comment: //search bar hider

$(document).on("pagechange", function () { 
     $(".ui-input-search").hide();
  });


// message listener


window.addEventListener("message", recieveMessage(event) {}, false)

function recieveMessage(event)



//list filter 

$("#clearFilterBtn").on("click", function () {
    $(".ui-input-search > input").val("").keyup();
});
$("#filterBtn").on("click", function () {
    $(".ui-input-search > input").val("nasdaq").keyup();
});

but by doing that it shows the search bar, i have no clue why

Comment: Well since you need to access the list from outside the iframe, you'll have to do things a bit differently. The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery) shows some ways to go about it.