# Call parent jquery function from inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this page "index.php" and in it I have this link that calls a pop up box:

```
<a href="#" id="signinlink">Sign in</a>
```

the jquery function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(function() {
        function launch() {
             jQuery('#sign_up').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { jQuery('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()}});
        }
        jQuery('#signinlink').click(function(e) {
            jQuery("#sign_up").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
                jQuery("#sign_up").find("input:first").focus();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**How from iframe to call this function?**

(* the iframe is called from parent page "index.php") 
I think i must  add a link with

```
window.parent.callme();
```

But how? please help!

Comment: Is the iframe within the same domain?

Comment: Yes it is the same domain

Comment: parent.document.getElementById("signinlink").click()

Comment: @mplungjan It looks like pseudocode you put here. for the jquery to work, there's a bit more to do...

Comment: What is `jQuery(function() {\* Do something*\});` doing there?

Comment: Plus you will find a lot of questions already on SO. So I am flagging it.

Comment: @naugtur nope. Not pseudo code. Just clicking the link in the parent frame. Should work, assuming the event handler is setup correctly I am using plain Dom access since OP has not told us if there is jquery loaded in the iframe

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, I just didn't get it that `click()` could be what OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - if the iframe is something to do with login form - it should send its own content itself. The code should be there, not get called in the parent frame.

Anyway, your question is missing some details on what exactly you want to do.

To access stuff from parent you do:

`window.parent.functionname()` instead of just `functionname()`

So

`$(document).find(...)` would become `window.parent.$(window.parent.document).find(...)`

To access the iframe from the parent, you need to fetch contentDocument of the iframe DOM node.

This is also helpful: [How to expose IFrame's DOM using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery)

If you can make your question clearer, it might be possible to show you an example of code that works with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - but only if I set jQuery to 1.8 OR add [jQuery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) since the lightbox-me needs the deprecated in 1.8 and deleted in 1.9 browser detection code

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/hSC4R/show/)

in iframe (assuming no jQuery in iFrame):

```
<a id="parentsignin" href="#">Signup</a>
```

using

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("parentsignin").onclick=function() {
    parent.document.getElementById('signinlink').click();
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

Actually, you might want to do this in parent - notice I cancel the link itself with preventDefault and reuse the code:

```
function launch() {
  $('#sign_up').lightbox_me({ 
    centered: true, 
    onLoad: function() { 
      $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus();
    }
  });
}


$(function() {
  $('#signinlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link from being followed
    launch(); 
  });
});
```