# Jquery selector for hiding element that has an children element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

This is a sample html

```
<iframe id="theiframe">
...
<form>
    <div class="pluginConnectButton">
        <div class="pluginButton pluginButtonInline pluginConnectButtonDisconnected" title="">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="pluginButton pluginButtonPressed pluginButtonInline pluginButtonX pluginConnectButtonConnected hidden_elem" title="">
            ...
        </div>
</form>
...
</iframe>
```

I want if the div with class pluginButton pluginButtonInline pluginConnectButtonDisconnected has class "hidden_elem" and is in the iframe with id = theiframe, then to do some action

Comment: have a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vt8WW/

```
alert($('#theiframe').hasClass('hidden_elem'));
```

Use it like this

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var el = $('.pluginButton.pluginButtonInline.pluginConnectButtonDisconnected');
if(el.hasClass('hidden_elem') && el.closest('#theiframe').length){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: @МихаилШахов is the script running within iframe or from parent window

Comment: i think i missunderstand but it's after the iframe. I tried it here but http://jsfiddle.net/vt8WW/ ...

Comment: @МихаилШахов I don't think you can pass content to iframe like that, you need to use the `src` attribute of the iframe to load content to iframe

Comment: no i just want if there is such an element to hide the whole iframe