# How to get the href link from iframe

Tags: jquery, html

```
      my html content is in iframe.
        <iframe id="test" name=""src="test.html">
        .....content from test.html

      </iframe>
```

test.html(in my server) has a link like

```
         <div id="division"><a  href="www.google.com"></a></div>
```

jquery

```
              $(document).ready(function() {
           var value=$("#division").find('a').attr('href');
        alert(value);
                }
```

question:alert(value) returns undefined

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the iframe has loaded, you'll have to use `contents()` to get the content, and then search and get the href property of the anchor, and the loaded content can't be cross domain, same origin policy etc :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').on('load', function() {
        var value = $(this).contents().find("#division a").prop('href');
        alert(value);
    });
});
```