# How to Count the number of links in a iframe tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<iframe  id="frame" style=" width:100%; height: 700px;    margin:30px 0 0 0px;
                         border-style: none; " src="" ></iframe>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("frame");
    var y =  x.contentDocument;
    if (y.document)y = y.document;
    y.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   //  alert("c");
     //   window.alert(5 + 6);
        x.src="some_link";
//document.write("k");
var xx = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');
//alert(xx);
var j = 0;
while (xx[j]){
xx[j].setAttribute('href', '');
alert("h"+j);
j++;
}
}

</script>
```

```
    var xx = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');
    There is error in this line i guess.
Not able to retrieve the links.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the href link from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906868/how-to-get-the-href-link-from-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

[How to get the href link from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906868/how-to-get-the-href-link-from-iframe)

Here is a example using Jquery, but you can do that using pure javascript.

After all that, you can use the Jquery property, length. It's easier.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the parent `document`

```
var xx = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');
         ^
```

Instead, use the `y` variable which has the frame's document

```
 var y =  x.contentDocument;
            ^

 if (y.document)y = y.document;
                      ^
```

Assign to `y` the right `document` object

```
y = x.contentWindow.document
```

**Use the following line of code:**

```
var xx = y.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName is no such property of y

Comment: Look the updated answer.  Assign `y = x.contentWindow.document` in order to get the right document object.

Comment: If i replace the some_link with the https://vjudge.net/contest/209723. I am not able to get the links.What is the error, can you help.The html collection is of lenghth zero.why it is not collecting the links