# Iframe, jquery keypress

Tags: javascript, iframe, event-handling, impress.js

I would like to know why my code does not work , any help appreciated.

I want to apply the following css to an Iframe when I hit the escape key, when the dynamically loaded from the same domain (its on the server, not on a remote server) iframe has the focus.

```
        $("document").on("keyup", $('#tiny-iframe').contentWindow.document , (function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                    $('#full-pres, #tiny-iframe').css({
                            "width": "400px",
                            "min-width": "350px",
                            "position": "relative",
                            "height":"240px"
                    });
            }
        });
```

This HTML is the iframe html:

```
            <!doctype html>
              <html>
            <head>
                <meta name='viewport' content='width=1024'/>   
                <title>Presentation Impress</title>
                <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'> 
                <style> p {font-size:70px;}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>  
                 <div id='jmpress'>
                  <div id='impress'>
                    <div id='first' class='step ' data-x='0' data-y='0'>
                     <p >Première acétate. </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/static/javascripts/impress.js'> </script>     
                <script>impress().init();</script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

goes in a div#tiny-iframe which is in a div#full-pres in my main html page.
The code above is loaded via ajax.

THIS POST

[How to expose IFrame's DOM using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery)
was very helpfull.

Comment: Can you explain why you use an iframe at all? Can't you call an URL that returns partial HTML that contains the data you need displayed?

Comment: Try using a div instead of an iframe. There must be a way to tell impress.js to do its work on a container div. See this post : https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/issues/111

Answer (score 0):

You can only do what you are trying to do if the iFrame is in the same domain.

Otherwise the browser will prevent it.

Comment: It is not on a remote domain.

Comment: huh ? I got it in ajax from my own server , the same who provides the web page containing this script.

Comment: @MaximeG what does your HTML look like?

Comment: @Maxime G Why do you use an iframe at all? Why not use a div? See $("#target-div").load(url) (http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Because I have to if I don't want the presentation element to fly by my main page (when the presentation is smaller (in the main page, not fullscreen)).

Comment: Do you think it can do what I need ?