# Post Message sending to the frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, postmessage

I have a hidden frame that Accepted message, but I do not have to send by clicking. I'm calling the function that performs and actions, including sending a message. Function settimeout not satisfied by their speed.

```
this.request = function (requestData) {
    $(function () {
        dataOrign = requestData;
        var iframe = $('iframe#postFrame');
        setTimeout(function () {
            var parseData = JSON.stringify(requestData);
            iframe[0].contentWindow.postMessage({ request: parseData }, '*');
        }, 1000);
    });
};
```

How can i send postMessage with minimal time? In this situation?

Comment: By the way, in IE8 (& I think 9), window.postMessage does not allow posting objects, only strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most browsers, you can listen for the `load` event (some example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery/11874986#11874986)) for that iframe to do the postMessage.

E.g.

```
$('iframe#postFrame').on('load', function(e) { 
    // do postMessage here
});
```

However it appears that the setTimeout/setInterval method is unavoidable for older browsers (IE7/8).

**UPDATE**

If you would like to write it as a function, you could do this:

```
var request = function(requestData, $iframe) { 
    if ($iframe.length > 0 && $iframe.get(0).document.readyState === 'completed') { 
        // do postMessage
    }
};
```

Then you can just use it this way:

```
request(data, $('iframe#postFrame'));
```

Comment: for the first sending it's good. But i use my function many times. For more information: I have the task to replace ajax requests for similar work on postMessage