# How to hide a div inside iframe?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, html, iframe

I am loading a view using iframe.Now i wants to hide a div inside the iFrame using jQuery. But  it shows $ is not defined.jQuery file is already included there.How can i do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#wrap").hide();  
    });                     
</script>
```

Comment: Have you added jQuery library?

Comment: What is your HTML structure? Is the jquery code in the iFrame? or in the parent page?

Comment: is jQuery included in the iframe or in the main page ? but basically on the main page you can't access the iframe content... 

This is the security policy

Comment: is your iframe URL belongs to the same domain.

Comment: You cannot change properties on divs inside iframe if iframe is not i same domain :)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ..

Comment: try searching questions like these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery which might have your answer and study the [jquery contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) api.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has some major issues with iframes. You'll have to include a script inside your iframe and go from there.

What are you trying to use as a trigger to hide the div?

If it's at all possible I would suggest not using iframes for your website. Iframes come in handy when you're trying to embed a youtube video or something.