# How to stop audio in an iframe using web audio api after hiding its container div?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, iframe, web-audio-api

I have an iframe where users can play/stop audio (using web audio api). But how can I stop audio if I hide that iframe? (e.g., by setting the CSS property `containerDiv.css('display', 'none')`). I've tried to clear the parent div with `containerDiv.html('')`, but audio inside iframe still keeps playing.

Comment: You can't. Can you explain the use case as it might help us provide a different solution?

Comment: I have a tetris game inside an iframe that appears when users complete a task, waiting for other tasks. The tetris application (in javascript as well) has sounds and controls to manage those. But, when a new task is ready, that iframe has to be hidden. Now the problem is that if users previously enabled audio, then it keeps playing.

Comment: I assume you control the parent and child frames, in which case you can use the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to communicate with the iframe. This would allow you to send a message to the iframe telling it to stop the audio.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that. I'll try and I'll let you know. In the meantime, if you want, you can propose your answer so that I can vote it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to communicate with the iframe. This would allow you to send a message to the iframe telling it to stop the audio.

A script in the parent window:

```
// Assuming the origin of your iframe is http://example.org
function hideTetrisIframe(){
  var iframe = document.getElementById('tetris');
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('stop', 'http://example.org'); 
}
```

A script inside the iframe:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.data === 'stop') {
    // Stop audio that's playing
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Yes, I've already implemented a similar mechanism by following your last comment. But now I'm facing the following error: `Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined onMessageReceived`. Do you any idea?

Comment: Ok, solved... using pure javascript it works fine. Previously I was using jquery to get the iframe, but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you!

Comment: For a jquery solution, I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery