# Accessing div of parent window

Tags: javascript, css, html

Here is scenario I have a file `HTMLPage1.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">

            #UrduPara 
           {
                float: right;
           }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="UrduPara">
              bla bla bla .....
        </div>

        <iframe src="HTMLPage2.html" width="1000" height="300"></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

Code foe second file `HTMLPage2.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTMLPage2.html</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.parent.document.getElementById("UrduPara").style.color = "green";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As I am trying to change color of `div` with `id` of `UrduPara` in `HTMLPage1.html`. But it does not work I am getting following error.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports
>   must match. HTMLPage2.html:40

**Note:** I am loading `HTMLPage1.html` while testing and this is the way I want it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery

Comment: Are you opening these via the `file` protocol? That's the only explanation I've ever seen for an origin to be null.

Comment: @scragar yes, something like this `file:///C:/Users/..`

Comment: @user3461957 That will be the issue then, try running it from a proper webserver and the issue should go away. If you're running windows I suggest install XAMPP, linux and Mac users should just install apache.

Comment: What does origin of frame mean? @scragar

Comment: Origin refers to where the frame comes from, the file protocol doesn't have one because they're local files, they've not come from any sort of web address. For this site it's `stackoverflow.com`, and only sites who's origin matches are, by default, allowed to access it's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null".

HTML documents from the file system are restricted from accessing other files for security reasons.

Host your files on an HTTP server. You can install one locally on your development computer.