# Detect iframe events with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this ajax code:

```
function send(obj) {
    var paket = {
        Url: obj
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(paket),
        success: function (data) {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
            var html = data.msg;
            iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
            renderat = true;
            $('frame').ready(function () {
                console.log("laddad");
                test();
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    })
}
```

Which works fine, it renders the html in my iframe:

```
<iframe width="600" height="600" id="frame"></iframe>
```

And then I use this to be able to pickup what elements are being used inside the iframe:

```
function test() {
    if (renderat == true) {
        console.log("0");
            var framen = document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow;
            $(framen).click(function (event) {
                alert($(event.target).val());
            });
    }
}
```

The problem is that it only runs up to console.log("0") and then nothing happens.. Why? I suspect the problem lies in that i cant figure out how to put this jquery code inside of $(document).ready?

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Most likely the 'framen' is empty, dump that in console too - also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

`ready()` is not valid on iframe as a selector, use `load` event

```
$('#frame').on('load',function () {
     console.log("laddad");
     test();
});
```

Comment: user said it runs to '0' in the log - therefor the test is being called - so no need to use the load.

Comment: @Leon suggest you read up on how `ready()` works. It references the main page which is already in `ready` state

Comment: if you want to get events from the DOM it doesn't matter if all (or none) elements are loaded except for the DOM - TS wants to handle the click event on the DOM, so ready is good. Since the Console.Log('0') is called the ready event has fired. Or am I mistaking?

Comment: @Leon yes you are mistaken, OP is trying to access a new DOM inside iframe and you can't do that until it is loaded

Comment: Thank you for your response, the current code is as follows:

$('#frame').on('load', function () {
                    $(iframe).mouseover(function (event) {
                        alert($(event.target));
                    });
                });

It wont let me add .contentWindow - then it throws me an security error, even though everything is happening on my own computer.

Comment: that mouseover code won't access targets inside the iframe.

Comment: Has nothing to do with computer, has to do with domain and `same origin policy`. Is page being run on localhost?

Comment: Yes running on localhost