# Web Scraping that Requires User Interaction

Tags: json, vba, web-scraping, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to scrape a site https://ibotta.com/rebates that requires you to scroll down and when it hits the bottom, loads more items.  Its a finite amount of items so I know it won't be scrolling forever but is there any method of doing this without having to interact with a browser object.

I'm trying to accomplish this in VB / VBA but any language would do.  Right now I templated it in MS Access just to get a feeling for how the site reacts, I can do it with the browser control loaded but its clunky.  Preferably something I can just make an HTTP call to.

On a side note, are they any good web scraping tutorials out their I should be looking at?

Comment: Please post in your question target page URL with explanation what data you need or code you have.

Comment: https://ibotta.com/rebates

Comment: The only response I have "We couldn’t find any All Rebates.
Try using fewer filters.". Regarding how to make XHR take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35700277/2165759).

Comment: What zip code you are intend to use on this site? That is for testing purpose.

Comment: Any really but 11590 will work (Westbury, NY)

Answer (score 1):

At the first sight XHRs I examined in Chrome - Developer tools - Network tab show that all the necessary data located in 2 files: `retailers.json` (15.7 kB) and `offers.json` (299 kB). While you are scrolling down the page actually no additional data is dowloaded, so I made a conclusion that scripts on the page just fetch data from that already downloaded files and put items to the page. I checked parameters and headers of the XHRs, and created the below simple VBS, which downloads the files:

```vb
strZipCode = "11590" ' your zip code here
strPathRetailers = "C:\retailers.json" ' retailers output file path
strPathOffers = "C:\offers.json" ' offers output file path

' make XHR to retrieve initial page with X-App-Token and X-NewRelic-ID
strURL = "https://ibotta.com/rebates"
XmlHttpRequest "GET", strURL, "", "", "", strResp

' extract X-App-Token eg 'loader_config={xpid:"VQAHUlVUGwcJUlBWBQg="}'
arrTmp = Split(strResp, "loader_config={xpid:""", 2)
strTmp = arrTmp(1)
arrTmp = Split(strTmp, """}", 2)
strNewRelicID = arrTmp(0)

' extract X-NewRelic-ID eg '<meta name="ibotta-t" content="nce0dc967myuho7wco:1458857196:91bf12dcd5442cf6b2100c962c656a510738150a">'
arrTmp = Split(strResp, "<meta name=""ibotta-t"" content=""", 2)
strTmp = arrTmp(1)
arrTmp = Split(strTmp, """>", 2)
strAppToken = arrTmp(0)

' put headers to array
arrHeaders = Array( _
    Array("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript"), _
    Array("Accept-Encoding", "deflate"), _
    Array("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"), _
    Array("Connection", "keep-alive"), _
    Array("Host", "ibotta.com"), _
    Array("If-Modified-Since", "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 10:00:00 GMT"), _
    Array("Referer", "https", "//ibotta.com/rebates"), _
    Array("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"), _
    Array("X-App-Token", strAppToken), _
    Array("X-App-Version", "3.6:webapp"), _
    Array("X-NewRelic-ID", strNewRelicID), _
    Array("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest") _
)

' make XHR to retrieve retailers
strURL = "https://ibotta.com/web_v1/retailers.json?zip=" & strZipCode
XmlHttpRequest "GET", strURL, arrHeaders, "", "", strResp
' save retailers to file
WriteTextFile strResp, strPathRetailers, -1

' make XHR to retrieve offers
strURL = "https://ibotta.com/web_v1/offers.json"
XmlHttpRequest "GET", strURL, arrHeaders, "", "", strResp
' save offers to file
WriteTextFile strResp, strPathOffers, -1

Sub XmlHttpRequest(strMethod, strURL, arrSetHeaders, strFormData, strRespHeaders, strRespText)
    Dim arrHeader
    With CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .SetOption 2, 13056 ' SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
        .Open strMethod, strURL, False
        If IsArray(arrSetHeaders) Then
            For Each arrHeader In arrSetHeaders
                .SetRequestHeader arrHeader(0), arrHeader(1)
            Next
        End If
        .Send strFormData
        strRespHeaders = .GetAllResponseHeaders
        strRespText = .ResponseText
    End With
End Sub

Sub WriteTextFile(strContent, strPath, lngFormat)
    ' lngFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, 2, True, lngFormat)
        .Write (strContent)
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

You can save this code to the text file vith `.vbs` extension and run.

At the moment I can see there 857 offers totally, and 220 retailers for zip code 11590 (used JSON viewers, like built in Chrome, or via [web service](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)). If you want to process only the offers for zip code 11590, then you have to get the list of retailers' `id`, and filter out only the offers, that belong to the retailers from the list.

There is retailers screenshot, each of them has `id` (outlined with red):

[image: retailers]

And there is offers screenshot, each of them belongs to several retailers in `retailer_ids` (outlined with red also):

[image: offers]

Further processing depends on what you need. You can parse JSON string to object and interact it, or convert JSON string to Recordset to filter it.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thank you.