# Add stylesheet to iFrame in ASP.NET .MVC 3

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, stylesheet

**Outline**

I am trying to figure out how to inject or define stylesheet to iFrame in ASP.NET MVC3. I have gone through the existing threads on the above topic but none suits my case.I have one solution that define an user control (ParitalShimViewControl) which renders .CSHTML pages in aspx. Using the dll from that solution I refer it in another solution(where the main framework is) and integrate to the main solution. All the css, js files are kept in the main solution only.

**Problem**

What I do is, I define some functionality(creating controller,views and models) and render it using the PartialShimControl and map it to the main solution in one of the aspx pages.
Here I have a case where I need to use iFrame to call some cross-domain service and render the result on the .CSHTML file (i.e. the view), however the result needs to be formatted properly using stylesheets and unfortunately I cannot refer the stylesheets in the view as they are placed in the main solution.

**Question**

Hope the requirement is clear.
How do I refer to those css from the iFrame in the main solution or whatever way possible?

Hope I do not sound too confusing :(

Code:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/X.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="X.aspx.cs" Inherits="Online.Web.Pages.X" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="Online.CommonFramework" Namespace="Online.CommonFramework.BaseClasses"
    TagPrefix="CFBase" %>
    <%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/Shims/PartialViewShimControl.ascx" TagName="PartialViewShim" TagPrefix="UC" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="Online.Web" Namespace="Online.Web.ProviderWebParts.DashBoard"
    TagPrefix="DashBoardWebParts" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="Online.Web" Namespace="Online.Web.WebParts"
    TagPrefix="WebParts" %>
    <asp:Content ID="HeadContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head">
    <link href="/Content/css/Core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/css/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/css/Pods.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <%--<link href="/Pages/CSS/layoutHome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Pages/CSS/Master0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Pages/CSS/compNewLexis0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Pages/CSS/Search0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>
   </asp:Content>
   <asp:Content ID="MedLitBodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="LandingBody" runat="server">
    <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/api/N.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/api/Utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/apiWebStorage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/vendor/VendorMaster0.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/api/SearchResults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/vendor/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/vendor/handlebars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/vendor/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/vendor/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MedLit/Content/js/LA.MedLit.Core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MedLit/Content/js/LA.MedLit.MedicalResearch.js">    
   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MedLit/Content/js/LA.MedLit.CaseValueAssessment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/X/Content/js/L.X.BrowseTopics.js">  
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/X/Content/js/L.X.ToPDF.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $LAB
        .script('/JS/vendor/VendorMaster1.js')
        .script('/JS/api/N.Advance.Ajax.js').wait()
        .script('/JS/api/N.Advance.WebStorage.PageData.js')
        .script('/JS/api/N.Advance.Popup.js')
        .script('/JS/api/N.Advance.Events.js')
        .script('/JS/api/N.Advance.UI.js')
        .script('/JS/api/N.Advance.Transactional.js')
        .script('/JS/api/N.Advance.Middleware.js')
        .script('/JS/api/N.Advance.Ready.js')
        .wait(function () {
            $(LN.Advance.Ready.init);
        });            
    </script>
    <asp:ProxyWebPartManager ID="WProxyManager" runat="server">
        <StaticConnections>
            <asp:WebPartConnection ID="DashBoardWPC" ProviderID="DashBoardTabWP" ProviderConnectionPointID="TabWebPart"
                ConsumerID="DashBoardPageLogicWP" ConsumerConnectionPointID="TabSystem" />
            <asp:WebPartConnection ID="TabsToState" ProviderID="DashBoardTabWP" ProviderConnectionPointID="TabWebPart"
                ConsumerID="dashBoardStateProvider" ConsumerConnectionPointID="TabSystem" />
            <asp:WebPartConnection ID="StatePageContextToPageLogic" ProviderID="dashBoardStateProvider"
                ProviderConnectionPointID="DashBoardPageContextExport" ConsumerID="DashBoardPageLogicWP"
                ConsumerConnectionPointID="PageContext" />
        </StaticConnections>
    </asp:ProxyWebPartManager>
    <div class="pg-scroll-fixed lx-clear">
        <CFBase:BaseWebPartZone runat="server" ID="WPTopZone">
            <ZoneTemplate>
                <WebParts:TabWebPart runat="server" Description="DashBoard" ID="DashBoardTabWP" ChromType="None"
                    IsRMLogRequired="true" />
                <DashBoardWebParts:DashBoardStateWebPart runat="server" ID="dashBoardStateProvider"
                    ChromeType="None" ChromeState="Minimized" />
                <DashBoardWebParts:DashBoardPageLogic runat="server" ID="DashBoardPageLogicWP" ChromeType="None" />
            </ZoneTemplate>
        </CFBase:BaseWebPartZone>
     </div>
    <UC:PartialViewShim runat="server" ID="LandingPageIndex" Area="MedLit" Controller="Research"
        View="ResearchView" />
  </asp:Content>
```

Rendering css dynamically -

```
 $(function () {
            var $head = $("#frame").contents().find("head");
            $head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", href: '/Pages/CSS/layoutMedLitHome.css', type: "text/css" }));
            $head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", href: '/Pages/CSS/Master0.css', type: "text/css" }));
            $head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", href: '/Pages/CSS/compNewLexis0.css', type: "text/css" }));
            $head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", href: '/Pages/CSS/Search0.css', type: "text/css" }));
            alert('head:' + $head.val());
        });
```

Comment: http://www.jquery4u.com/dom-modification/jquery-change-css-iframe-content/#.UBpQ45xv9tA

Comment: @bPratik: I used to jQuery to inject the css dynamically but the thing is the results page is loaded only on click from the main page and the jQuery stuff is written on the main page :(

Comment: So inject it after the `iframe` loads. Without code samples of what you are doing it is difficult to give you any answer. Either link to the actual page where you are trying to do this, or setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751435/detecting-when-iframe-content-has-loaded-cross-browser

Comment: The CSS and JS files have to be written on this page, which renders multiple .chtml files based on user actions - rendering css dynamically

Comment: great edit, you are far more likely to get a response now. Having just glanced briefly at your code, is the issue arising because you are appending `<link/>` tags with relative css paths? You could also try fetching all the css styles out of those files using ajax and then appending that in the `<head/>` within a `<style/>` tag?

Comment: @bPratik: won't work coz the css is structured from a long inherited list, custom css framework, inline css can't be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, used div instead of iFrame to get the cross domain html and embedded it, that solved the problem of stylesheets!
But thanks a lot for your support.