# How to check whether iframe loads content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cookies

I have a site which embeds a survey from a different domain inside an iframe. However, in some browsers when third party cookies are disabled the iframe predictably is blank.

If the iframe does not load content I wish to show just a link instead of the iframe window itself, with javascript. So far I have

```
<iframe id="iframe" onload='setFrameLoaded();' width="600" height="500" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

and the script

```
var frame_loaded = 0;
function setFrameLoaded() {
    frame_loaded = 1;
}
```

But when I change the source to *about:blank* the iframe still loads okay (again, probably expected behaviour).

Can I check whether the iframe has content loaded (despite it being from a different domain)?

Comment: The answer is you can not do it without help from the other domain.

Comment: Check this out: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751435/detecting-when-iframe-content-has-loaded-cross-browser