# Comfirm iframe src change

Tags: javascript, iframe, vimeo

i'm using vimeo for my video. I have a button that fades the screen to black and loads image assets and changes the src of the iframe video. Then fades back in.

But the iframe video changes after the black fades in.

Is there a way i can comfirm that the new src has been loaded before i initiate the iframe?

Comment: [This should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751435/detecting-when-iframe-content-has-loaded-cross-browser)

Comment: awesome that did it!!