# Chrome Extension: detecting keypresses in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey my friends and I new to javascript and are encountering problems with some code. 
Currently we're trying to make a chrome extension that detects when and how much a user works on a particular google document, by detecting keystrokes.

Our current method involves creating a 'keypress' event listener. We put it into a content.js file that runs on any docs.google webpage. The thing is, it works when you're on the page editing the title/anything else, but for some reason it doesnt register when the user is actually editing the document. We tried it on other websites and it works, and adding it to background.js doesn't work.

```
var handler = function (e) { 
    handler.data.push(e);
    console.log("success");
    console.log(handler.data);
}
handler.data = [];
window.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
```

So we tried to change the permissions on the 'iframe' of the google docs document so that we could use content scripts but it still didn't work (here's the code)

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
divs[i].sandbox = 'allow-scripts'
divs[i].addEventListener('keydown', handler, true);
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see iframes used for the main content on g-docs or g-sheets, but if you insist you can use ["all_frames": true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#all_frames) and ["match_about_blank": true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match_about_blank) in manifest.json content script declaration to make it run in all iframes automatically.

Another idea is to capture events before the site sees them: declare ["run_at": "document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at) for your content script in manifest.json and use `true` for [useCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) parameter of addEventListener: `document.addEventListener("keydown", handler, true);` - this line should be executed in the main code of your content script to register the listener before the page DOM is built, don't put it inside some `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` callback.

Comment: We tried editing our code (http://imgur.com/a/wWNqS) but we're still getting the error message (http://imgur.com/a/9KbbR)

Comment: This is a really great answer(as always), unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working for me right now. From looking at `getEventListeners(document)["keydown"];` in devtools, I think the GDocs page is actually removing the event listeners once it loads- my listeners exist when I create them at `doc_start`, but once we get past `load`, they're gone.

Comment: @KarlReid, the events are captured in iframe with `docs-texteventtarget-iframe` class so the answer should work. You can verify it in devtools by inspecting inside this iframe so that console toolbar context selector changes to the iframe, then run  `document.addEventListener("keydown", console.log)` and type something in the gdocs editor.

Comment: Thanks, knowing the class is very helpful. The toolbar selector doesn't actually have this frame for me, but it is there because I can find it with a querySelector. Anyway, I've actually found that just `match_about_blank` seems  to work perfectly for my application- presumably it gets my script injected into that frame while `all_frames` didn't, and then all is well. Don't need `document_start` in the end. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question (detect and use keypress in google docs) and that page gave me the solution : http://features.jsomers.net/how-i-reverse-engineered-google-docs/

```
var editingIFrame = $('iframe.docs-texteventtarget-iframe')[0];
      if (editingIFrame) {
        editingIFrame.contentDocument.addEventListener("keydown", hook, false);
      }
    function hook(e){
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        console.log("keycode:" + keyCode);    
}
```

hope it can help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Hope this may help you !!//
<pre>
var events = document.createEvent('Event');
events.initEvent('keyup',true,true);
var elem = document.querySelector(".docs-texteventtarget-iframe").contentDocument.activeElement;
elem.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
console.log('check check')
console.log(elem);},false);
elem.dispatchEvent(events);
</pre>
```