# Google docs : click a button or change style with userscript (tampermonkey)

Tags: javascript, google-docs, userscripts, tampermonkey

I would like to have keyboard shortcuts to change the color of a selected text in google docs.

I am able to get the button elements by id but when I send `click()` to that element nothing happen (here is my try with the bold button used for debug because it's simpler than what I want to do with button `textColorButton` )

```
var button = document.getElementById("boldButton");
alert(button.innerHTML);   // working
button.click();   // not working
```

I also though about getting the selection and then apply a style but the getSelection is empty:

```
var text = document.getSelection();
alert(text);  // empty
```

Here is my script so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google docs
// @match        https://docs.google.com/document/d/#######
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// @require    http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sugar/1.3/sugar.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var editingIFrame = $('iframe.docs-texteventtarget-iframe')[0];
if (editingIFrame) {
    editingIFrame.contentDocument.addEventListener("keydown", hook, false);
}
function hook(key) { 
    if (key.ctrlKey  &&  key.altKey  &&  key.code === "KeyE") {
        var button = document.getElementById("boldButton");
        button.click();   // not working
    }
}
```

Comment: Try button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles:true}))

Comment: Thanks for your help wOxxoM but still, it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to click a button is to do this:

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
button.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Here is the full script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google docs
// @match        https://docs.google.com/document/d/#########
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
// sources:
// for iframe https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217408/3154274
// for switch https://stackoverflow.com/q/13362028/3154274
// combinaison of key  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37559790/3154274
// dispatchEvent https://stackoverflow.com/a/33887557/3154274
var editingIFrame = $('iframe.docs-texteventtarget-iframe')[0];
if (editingIFrame) {
    editingIFrame.contentDocument.addEventListener("keydown", hook, false);
}

function hook(key) {
    if (key.ctrlKey && key.altKey && key.code === "KeyY") {
        var button = document.getElementById("textColorButton");
        var color = document.querySelector('[title="light red berry 3"]');
        triggerMouseEvent(button, "mouseover");
        triggerMouseEvent(button, "mousedown");
        triggerMouseEvent(button, "mouseup");
        triggerMouseEvent(color, "mouseover");
        triggerMouseEvent(color, "mousedown");
        triggerMouseEvent(color, "mouseup");
    }

}

function triggerMouseEvent(node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}
```