# iframe events when finish load it run twice when first access the iframe's page and when finish loading, with angular2+ ,

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe, ionic3

How can I detect an iframe finish event in angular4 mainly (angular 2+) ?
I just have normal iframe like this:

```
<iframe [src]="..." onLoad=""></iframe>
```

i faced a problem that when i enter the page that include the iframe the onlaod function run directly (the src is not availbale) and it runs again when the src become available .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting when Iframe content has loaded (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751435/detecting-when-iframe-content-has-loaded-cross-browser)

Answer (score 2):

i make a condition on onload **if(this.src)** because i faced problem when i access the page that have the iframe onload run directly when src not available, and re run again when iframe loaded when src is available. 
I removed the loader when iframe is fully loaded .
so this is my solution:

```
<ion-spinner id="loader"  color="primary"></ion-spinner>
<iframe [src]="url"
        onload="if(this.src) document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none'"></iframe>
```

thank you. hope it help someone